# Exclude few @Component annotated classes in SpringBootTest

Tags: java, junit, annotations, spring-boot-test

I have few `@Component` annotated classes where I have initialized my configurers such as DBConfigurer, SecurityConfigurer, JmxConfigurer and many more.

While adding functional test, I want few classes should not be loaded. Can I exclude few configurers defined above.

My test class I have defined as shown below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { ServiceStarter.class }, properties = { "jmx.rmi.port=19057", "hostname=localhost" })
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ControllerTest.BeansOverrideConfigurer.class})
public class ControllerTest {
    // All test here.
}
```

I can go with defining selected configurers inside `@ContextConfiguration` block in test class, but that I don't want to go, as in future if someone adds a new configurer, it should get automatically imported in test case.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Profile on those components that you don't want to load during specific profiles e.g. testing (ie only during eg production and development).

```
@Component
@Profile("production")
public class ComponentClass {}
```

And then define the @ActiveProfile that you want to run during your tests e.g.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ControllerTest {}
```

You can ref to Spring Framework docs and Spring Boot docs for more info [docs.spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-adding-active-profiles)